# HTML to .doc on phone download Coldfusion

Tags: mobile, coldfusion, ms-word

I'm trying to get my html content to download and run in MSWord on mobile using Coldfusion. It currently downloads, runs, and opens correctly on a PC, but when I try to go on a phone it will not open. It downloads but says, "Can't open file."

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=test.docx">
<cfcontent type="application/vnd.word">
```

I have also tried:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=test.docx">
<cfcontent type="application/msword">
```

Does mobile handle HTML to MSWord differently than a desktop?

Comment: 1.) I imagine iOS and Android can be quite different from a desktop AND different from each other 2.) You might want to try a normal link rather than content disposition.

Comment: How was the file created in the first place?

Comment: I have it coded as coldfusion that loads from queries directly into an already created html page

Answer (score 1):

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/05/08/office-2007-file-format-mime-types-for-http-content-streaming-2/) the following are correct for MS Word (as of Office 2007:

- .doc: application/msword
- .docx: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

For whatever reason, it's possible that even with the correct mime-type, iOS or Android is still seeing the content as HTML.

You might take a look at https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j. Haven't tried myself, but might fit the bill.

Comment: Currently I have tried both .doc and .docx with the correct mime types. I'm not sure why its having a hard time loading in HTML